# Understanding GetDiBits. C++

Tags: winapi, dib, getdibits, createdibsection

MSDN says that the bitmap used in `GetDiBits` should not be selected into a DC before calling this function. But from my experience(with `BitBlt`) I know that I cannot draw an a bitmap unless it is selected.

1. How does `GetDiBits` circumvents this? Can I just use an unselected, newly created bitmap as argument to this function?
2. `GetDiBits` as well `CreateDibSection` returns an array. But MSDN says about the first function:

   > "bits of the specified compatible bitmap"

   I thought DI stands for DeviceIndependent. Why is there a contradiction? This means that, according to MSDN, `GetDiBits` can be used only with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` (which is DD)? Then I can't send this array to another machine to display it,right?
3. Both functions use a hDC. If `CreateDibSection` is truly DIndependent why does it need a hDC? All the needed info is provided through the bitmapinfoheader...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. I cannot draw an a bitmap unless it is selected. How does GetDiBits circumvents this?

GetDIBits doesn't do any drawing.  It reads pixel data from a bitmap and converts it into the desired color format.  SetDIBits doesn't "draw" either, but it will set the pixel data in a bitmap.

> 2. Naming confusion.

The DI in GetDIBitmap refers to the fact that the pixel data is *returned* in a device-independent format (specifically, the one you ask for).  The source bitmap can be a compatible bitmap or a device-independent bitmap.

Similarly SetDIBitmap takes device-independent pixel data and converts it to the type of the target bitmap.

These functions are confusingly named.

> 3. What's the DC for?

The DC is used to answer any questions about the pixel format on the device.  For example, if the source format is a palette-based device-dependent bitmap, GetDIBits will assume the palette selected into the DC is the correct one.  Note that the palette is not in the BITMAPINFOHEADER.

CreateDIBSection creates a hybrid bitmap that stashes data in a device-independent method, but may also keep a device-dependent copy in sync with it for performance.  So it needs to know the DC of the intended device.

Comment: GetDiBits returns an array. If I edit this array it will change the bitmap as well, right?(because it is a pointer to its memory...unless it is const). Then if edit the bmp this way, I am effectively coloring without any assistence from the hdc(no pallete ,size or whatever). Is this correct?

Comment: No, GetDIBits gives you a _copy_ of the pixel data (in the format you request).  If you want to change the bitmap, you can change that pixel data and then update the bitmap using SetDIBits.  And then you have to select it back into a memory DC and blit it again to see your change.

Comment: Thanks. CreateDibSection is more suited for this ,no?

Comment: Sure, but either way works.  Just watch for synchronization problems if you're using GDI to draw to the bitmap *and* trying to read and write the pixel data yourself.  (The MSDN page for CreateDIBSection has details.)

Comment: "_but may also keep a device-dependent copy in sync with it_" -- Where do you get that from?

Comment: @zett42:  From conversations with Windows evangelists many years ago.  They explained that the DIB stays in system memory (a file mapping object).  When you blit it, it has to be converted to the display's pixel format, and the converted data needs to be transferred to video memory.  A DIB section, they explained, may cache that DDB in video memory so that a second blit (assuming the DIB hasn't been altered) doesn't need to do the conversion and transfer again.  So, effectively, the DIB section may maintained as a DDB version in cache, which is re-sync'ed as needed.

Comment: @zett42:  I believe it was also explained in the _Windows 2000 Graphics API Black Book_ by Damon Chandler, but I finally recycled my copy so I can't easily double check.